# Azure Dev Ops creates resource and then does not see it

Tags: azure-devops, azure-keyvault, azure-deployment

I run a AzDO pipeline consisting of 2 stages.
[image]

Stage 1 (Create pre-ADF .. ) will check if there is a key vault exist in the Azure subscription/resource group.  If if it exists, it just passes through , if it does not - it will create it and populate with secrets (secrets are copied from another base key vault).
PowerShell code is very basic, and stage 1 works just fine

```
if ( -not(Get-AzKeyVault -VaultName $newKvName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -
    ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) )
{
  New-AzKeyVault -VaultName $newKvName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Location 
  $location

$Context = Get-AzContext
Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName $newKvName -ServicePrincipalName 
$Context.Account.Id -PermissionsToSecrets Get,List,Set

$secretNames = (Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $sourceKvName).Name
$secretNames.foreach{
    Write-Host Processing Secret Name $_
    Set-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $newKvName -Name $_ -SecretValue (Get-
    AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $sourceKvName -Name $_).SecretValue
}
}
else {
  Write-Host "Key Vault " $newKvName " already exists.  Not creating"
}
```

The stage 1 end with requirement to post aprove it.  So, before approving, I go in and check that Keyvault is there, and secrets are in.

**Then stage 2 comes in**

It will do few things

1. ) Create Data factory (using PowerShell) - THIS SUCCEEDS ALWAYS.
2. ) Then it will check new KeyVault creted in stage 1 and assign access policy to it for
   the data factory that was just created (1.)

Here is a code for step 2:

```
Set-AzDataFactoryV2 -ResourceGroupName $varDevResourceGrpName -Name $varDevDataFactory - 
Location $varLocation -Force
$principal = (Get-AzDataFactoryV2 -ResourceGroupName $varDevResourceGrpName -Name 
$varDevDataFactory).identity.PrincipalId
Write-Host "Data Factory Principal ID = $principal"
Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName $varKeyVault -ObjectId $principal - 
BypassObjectIdValidation -PermissionsToSecrets Get,List,Set
```

When the line `Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName $varKeyVault -ObjectId $principal -  BypassObjectIdValidation -PermissionsToSecrets Get,List,Set` executes,

pipeline complains that it does not see the KeyVault.

```
2023-01-13T15:52:23.1771395Z --------------------------------------------
2023-01-13T15:52:23.7513345Z Data Factory Principal ID = 783c84c1-008f-45f2-9349- 
39c04634fecb
2023-01-13T15:52:25.0779247Z ##[error]Vault 'dmKvTest' does not exist in current 
subscription.  If this vault exists in your tenant, please switch to the correct 
subscription in order to modify the Access Policies of this vault.
2023-01-13T15:52:25.1753010Z ##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
```

This error comes up OFTEN but not every time.  So, I am at loss and it need of help on how to troubleshoot.

Comment: Could you please tell if both your key vault and ADF are in the same subscription or in different subscriptions?

Comment: Yes, they are both in the same subscription.